# Parsing Youtube - Xpath to retrieve a Youtube Channel's Profile Picture and Description

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, youtube, xml-parsing

I would like to import the profile picture of a number of Youtube Channels into a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

This is the information that I have been able to retrieve so far:

[image]

To retrieve the **profile picture**, I have used the following code using Social Blade's website:

```
=IMPORTXML(D2,"//img[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoAvatar']")
```

However while it doesn't result in an erorr it doesn't retrieve the image from the src.  Any idea how to make it work?

In regard to the **description**, I would like to use a code that can be consistently used using either the channel's id or Youtube's username. Other solutions that I have tried have allowed me to get a truncated description, not the full one.

Maybe there is a more cost-effective way of doing this task, but without much Javascript experience this is the easiest way I have found to retrieve the information. Ideally, I would like to find a solution that calls on the Youtube API and bypasses the 50-call limit.

Here's a [sample Google Sheets template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dVQfhdanJY5gaoaEIRKZUJ2Lxkqg9ozZpeJBlj8y920/edit?usp=sharing) to work on a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I've edited your Google Sheet. You forgot the @src attribute for the image.

```
=IMAGE(IMPORTXML(E2;"//img[@id='YouTubeUserTopInfoAvatar']/@src"))
```

And I've added the XPath for the Youtube channel description (add "/about" at the end of the youtube channel links).

```
=IMPORTXML(C2,"//div[@class='about-description branded-page-box-padding']")
```

[image: Musc]
Note : You have to fix your "ChannelID" formula to extract the ID.

Comment: That makes total sense. I didn't quite get how to call src. Thanks again.